# Download Google Play APK by php

Tags: php, download, apk, google-play

I need to download google play android files (APK) by php,but as you know it doesn't promise to do it by pc.
How it works and how can I download apks by php?

Comment: Pretty sure Google doesn't want you doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably pick up some hints from this: http://codekiem.com/2012/02/24/apk-downloader/ -- the crx file for the extension can be unzipped.  It contains the source in javascript form, which performs some HTTP operations to download the APK.  It should be possible to replicate this in PHP.

Note:

1. This is a violation of the market ToS
2. This requires a google account and a device id

Comment: i can not find crx file from introducing link. can you help me to download it?

Comment: hi @frank-farmer i am nor able to find crx file. is there any other way achieve this.

Comment: As of point 1, does it mean that sites like evozi and Apkpure are doing it illegally?